# Evernoteアプリでmonacaデバッガとビルドされたアプリの差異をなくす方法

Tags: javascript, monaca, jquery, html5, oauth

monacaプラットフォームで、HTML5+Javascriptベースで、Evernoteアプリの開発を行っております。

[Evernoteのウェブサイト](https://dev.evernote.com/intl/jp/doc/start/javascript.php) 上からリンクが貼られていた、GitHub のサンプルコードを参考に実装をしました。

https://github.com/evernote/phonegap-example/blob/master/HelloWorld/www/js/index.js

関連部分のコードは上記のindex.jsから変えていません。

monacaデバッガ上では無事にOAuth認証してトークンを取得できます。

しかし、いざビルドしてAndroidの実端末で動作確認を行ったところ、OAuth認証をしようとするのですが、「【アプリ名】がアカウントにアクセスすることを許可　→　承認する」画面までは行くのですが、承認ボタンを押すと、「申し訳ございません。Evernote Web版はAndroidブラウザには対応していません。」と出て、トークンが取得できません。

monacaデバッガとビルドしたapkで何か（user agent等？）が異なるのだと存じますが、何が異なるか、または、この差異をなくす方法についてご存じの方がいらっしゃったら、お知恵をお菓子いただけないでしょうか。

ご多忙のところ、お手間をお掛けし恐縮です。

Comment: `window.open`が使われているので、Cordova`InAppBrowser`プラグインを有効にしてビルドして試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。ご示唆の通りの対応で動作しました。

プラグイン無しで全く動作しないならまだしも、半端にそれっぽい動作をするので見落としていました。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: Monacaデバッガーは基本的なプラグインがすでに組み込まれているので、同様のトラブルが多いようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。monacaのマニュアルには一通り目を通していたつもりだったのですが、確かに関連記載があったのを、後ほど思い出しました。全く動かないならまだしも、半端に動くので、見落としていました。

Answer (score 0):

`window.open`が使われているので、Cordova`InAppBrowser`プラグインを有効にしてビルドして試してみてください。

---

*この投稿は [@otak-lab さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20434/evernote%e3%82%a2%e3%83%97%e3%83%aa%e3%81%a7monaca%e3%83%87%e3%83%90%e3%83%83%e3%82%ac%e3%81%a8%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f%e3%82%a2%e3%83%97%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e5%b7%ae%e7%95%b0%e3%82%92%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%99%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment19187_20434) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*